# Compatibility of Avro contract with enum

Tags: avro

I have an existing avro schema

```html
{
"name": "myenum",
"type": {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    },
"default": null
}
```

I want to add null to be the default and updating the contract to the following result in backward compatibility error. what can be done to solve this issue

```html
{
"name": "myenum",
"type": [ null, {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    }],
"default": null
}
```

Comment: You already have a default of null. What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the `null` that is been added.

i.e.

```
{
    "name": "myenum",
    "type": [ null, { <- problem
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    }],
    "default": null
}
```

It should be within quotes: `null` => `"null"`. So updated definition will be like:

```
{
    "name": "myenum",
    "type": [ "null", { <- change
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "Suit",
        "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
    }],
    "default": null
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution to this problem